# Google Cloud ML Engine Hyperparameter Tuning: Any Advantage to Large machine?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I'm using ML Engine to run a hyperparameter tuning job for a Keras / Tensorflow model.  I originally had set the machine type to be `complex_model_l` which is $1.65/hour.  However, I'm using a `TFRecord`s saved on Google Cloud Storage for my training and validation sets.

Given that they only take up ~6GB of space combined, is there any need for such a large machine?  Could I use a `standard` machine (costs $0.27/hour) and run the tuning job as quickly?

Any advice would be awesome!  I'm just not sure to what degree Tensorflow can make use of multiple cores by default.

Thanks!

Comment: The requirement of machine type depends on your model, batch size and etc. You can try smaller machines to check if it works for you.